# At the time of speaking, no relation to present

Tags: present-perfect, past-tense, usage, past-perfect

My friend asked me, "Have you ever paid the money as a penalty?"

I paid some money as a penalty, but that was long ago; it won't effect the present.

What should I say?

> I have paid.

> I had paid.

> I paid.

Comment: Just as a reminder, common people don't speak thinking so specifically like you think they do. `I have paid` and `I paid`, both are fine unless you are speaking about strict Grammar. However `I had paid` is too large a wrong usage here. I would rather suggest you to go through a good Grammar book on tense to clear your concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's make up some details, so the difference between these sentences will be clearer.

Suppose that it is January, and last September your university sent you a bill charging you a $50 fine for registering late. They sent you another bill again in November, raising the fine to $75 because you were late paying it. If you still owe the money you will not be allowed to register today for this semester. Your friend asks:

> **Q1**: Have you paid that fine? ... *you answer:*
>   **A1**: Yes, I **have paid** it.

You answer using the present perfect for two reasons: **1)** Your friend's question used the present perfect, and we usually match the tenses in question and answer.  **2)** The present perfect expresses a past action which establishes a present state. You understand, because your friend uses the present perfect, that she is asking about your current status, and you answer with a statement about your present status.

Note, however, that if you want to tell her **when** you paid, you must employ the past tense, because now you are speaking of the event relative to that date:

> **Q2**: Have you paid that fine? ... *you answer:*
>   **A2**: Yes, I **paid** in December.

Suppose now that your friend asks:

> **Q3**: Did you pay that $75 fine? ... *perhaps you answer:*
>   **A3**: Yes, I **paid** it.

In this case your friend is not asking about your present status but about a past fact; so both of you use the past tense. However, it is also possible that you return a different answer:

> **Q4**: Did you pay that $75 fine? ... *and you answer:*
>   **A4**: No; I **didn't pay** the extra $25 because I **had paid** the $50 fine in October.

Both of you are talking about your past action relative to the November bill, and you cast that in the past tense, as in Q3/A3; but when you add information about something which happened *before* November, you must cast that in the *past perfect*.

Comment: You might also answer *"No, I haven't paid it **yet**"*, but *"No, I **didn't pay** it yet"* is an unlikely form.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are answering a question, which uses the present perfect, your answer should be "Yes, I have." or "No, I haven't." You could also simply answer with "Yes." or "No."

If then you want to add when it happened, you can add "It happened time ago."

Answer (score 0):

The question is incorrect. It should be:

> "Have you ever paid money as a penalty?"

In fact, it should be:

> "Have you ever paid a [fine](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fine)?"

(fine (noun): "3 a : a sum imposed as punishment for an offense b : a forfeiture or penalty paid to an injured party in a civil action"

Your answer should be:

> Yes.

or

> Yes, I have.

or

> Yes, once I paid a fine as a penalty, but that was a long time ago. It shouldn't be important now.